# Frequency response of linear DDS chirp

Tags: dac, frequency-response, dds

I am performing a linear frequency sweep from 80 MHz to 120 MHz in 26.84 ms with the AD9910 direct digital synthesiser. I experience that the output amplitude is not constant (see Figure 1).

[image: Fig. 1]

With my basic understanding about digital signal synthesis I though this has to do with the [zeroth order hold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-order_hold) of the DAC. However the system clock runs at 1 GHz and therewith 100 MHz is far away from half the sampling frequency. Further the enabled inverse-sinc filter of the AD9910 does not compensate for the response.

So my next idea was that there may be some problem with the digital ramp used to perform the linear chirp. To check this hypothesis I configured the DDS registers to output a constant output signal and incremented the frequency of the output signal manually using the main registers and no digital ramp. The results are presented in Figure 2. There is indeed a slight difference in shape, however the global characteristics stay in place.

[image: Fig. 2]

**So far I cannot explain the origins of the observed amplitude response. I would be interested if this corresponds to known DAC characteristics or if there may be other reasons?**

On the measurement details:
*The presented amplitude response was obtained by delaying the external trigger signal through a square wave signal generator. By adjusting the square wave width and having the oscilloscope trigger on the falling edge of the trigger signal I was able to capture multiple time windows and still resolve a fine enough signal to perform FFT. For every time window I extracted the frequency with the maximum power spectrum and the maximum amplitude of the signal (this is what you see in the plot).*

Comment: You need to look at the signal with an oscilloscope.

Comment: Measure the peak-to-peak amplitude with the oscilloscope in the time domain to confirm if this is really correct. At this frequency, you need to use 50 Ohm cabling and 50-ohm termination on the oscilloscope. Reflections in the cable could produce amplitude variations. Please update the question to include more details about cabling and termination.

Comment: 50 Ohm coaxial cables where used, however oscilloscope was set to 50 M Ohm. Can you recommend a reliable method to extract peak-to-peak amplitude from the oscilloscope (curve fitting does not work well).

Comment: Use horizontal cursors or automatic measurement feature of the oscilloscope. If the scope cannot be set to have 50 Ohm input impedance, then you need to add a 50 Ohm BNC terminator right at the scope (or a 49.9 Ohm resistor with very short leads, close to oscilloscope).

Comment: Is the cable, by any chance, around 4.3 meters long?

Comment: @mkeith that can indeed be the case, but I cannot say for sure as the line comprises multiple segments. I now measured with oscilloscope at 50 Ohm and indeed output voltage is stable. Would you mind to expand your comment as answer so I can mark it?